# How to add dummy interfaces for a container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm building a test environment for some software that, once deployed, should see some network interfaces.

I don't need the interfaces to be interactive, only that they appear using `ip link show`. 
Using `ip link add dummy0 type dummy` works only when directly executed on the shell, while it fails in scripts or Dockerfile RUN with `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`.

I am using docker-compose to set up and link multiple containers, however only one of those needs the dummy interfaces.

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` is missing.

Follow these steps:

- Create `Dockerfile` with contents:

```
FROM alpine
COPY script.sh /script.sh
RUN chmod +x /script.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/script.sh"]
```

- Create `script.sh` with contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip link add dummy0 type dummy
tail -f /dev/null
exec "$@"
```

- Build docker container `docker build -t myimage:v1 .`
- Run docker container without --cap-add option

```
$ docker run -itd myimage:v1
$ docker logs container-id
ip: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

- Run docker container with `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` option.

```
$ docker run -itd --cap-add=NET_ADMIN myimage:v1
$ docker exec -it container-id sh
/ # ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether c2:ad:ec:b9:7c:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
37: eth0@if38: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
/ #
```

*NOTE: You can see dummy0 interface created.*

`--cap-add` or `--cap-drop` are the option that you can use with docker run to add or drop any particular [linux capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).

For more info, I highly recommend to go through [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities).

By default docker have few linux capabilities enabled and other disabled, which are listed [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities).

In case of docker-compose use [cap_add](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#cap_add-cap_drop) option.

Comment: I can confirm this works, however it seems I can't connect to the container via ssh now. My image is based on [ubuntu-sshd](https://hub.docker.com/r/rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd/). The error I receive now is `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

Comment: Sorry no idea maybe you can ask a new question for this on stackoverflow. If my answer worked please upvote and accept it. :)

Comment: The issue was that the `ENTRYPOINT` command overrides `CMD` of the base image, which in this case was `/usr/sbin/sshd -D`. Adding it to the script fixed the issue.